# Angular 1.6.x: how to redirect from one controller to homepage using ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I have a `contact page` and there is a `home btn` on that page. I want to redirect it from `contact page` to `home page` using ng-click.

below is the code for respective pages.

`contact.html`

```
<div ngController="contactController">
        <div class="heading text-center">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="validationTooltip01" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltipName" placeholder="Name" required>
                    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                        Please enter your full name.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="validationTooltipEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="validationTooltipUsernamePrepend">@</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="validationTooltipEmail" placeholder="Email" 
                    aria-describedby="validationTooltipUsernamePrepend" required>
                    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                        Please choose a valid email.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="validationTooltip03" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Query</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltipQuery" placeholder="Query" required>
                    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                        Please write your Query.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group offset-md-5">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="homebtn" ng-click="home()">Home</button>  
            </div>
          </form>
    </div>
</div
```

`contact.component.js`

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .component('contactComponent', {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},    
  templateUrl:'contact/contact.html',
  controller: contactController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  // bindings:{
  //   information:'='
  // }

});

function contactController() {
 };
```

`app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.controller('mainCtrl',function(){

});

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        component: 'dashboardComponent'
      })
      .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        component: 'contactComponent'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        component: 'aboutComponent'
      })

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="homebtn" ng-click="navigate ('home')">Home</button>
```

and in controller,

```
$scope.navigate = function(routeName){
  $state.go(routeName)
};
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I tried it, but no luck. I am probably missing something. Could you please edit your solution with a bit more detail. thanks a mil

Comment: `function contactController($scope) {
  $scope.navigate = function(home){
    $state.go(home)
  };
  
};`

Comment: you need to inject $state to the controller as a parameter

Comment: I tried. I get the error `$Scope is not defined` 

`angular.module('myApp')
  .component('contactComponent', {
  restrict: 'E',
  $scope: 'home',    
  templateUrl:'contact/contact.html',
  controller: contactController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
});

function contactController($state) {
  $scope.navigate = function(home){
    $state.go(home)
  };
  
};`

Comment: You are missing something

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have written

> ngController="contactController"

It should be

```
<div ng-controller="contactController">
```

After that change your **contactController** as following. Put it after module initialization.

```
app.controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
        $scope.home = function () {
            $state.go('home');
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: down-voter, can you comment the reason of downvoting

Comment: I placed this code inside my `app.js` after module initialization. there are no errors but the btn click does not work.

Comment: Did you see any error in your console. Try putting console.log in the function and check if it is being called or not?

Comment: yes I checked the console. No errors there and no, the function isn't called.

Comment: @NaumanTanwir i just noticed you are using <div ngController="contactController"> i think it should be ng-controller

Comment: Tried that. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.

```
    function contactController($scope, $state) {
  $scope.navigate = function(home){
    $state.go(home)
  };

};
```

I was missing $scope as a parameter inside my controller function.